# differential equation into state space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, control-theory

I have this dynamic system

$$
J \ddot{\theta} + F\dot{\theta} = u
$$

I would like to acquire the state space of the system. This is what I've done
$$
x_{1} = \theta, \\
x_{2} = \dot{\theta}, \\
x_{3} = \ddot{\theta} \\
\dot{x_{1}} = x_{2} \\
\dot{x_{2}} = \ddot{\theta} = \frac{1}{J}u - \frac{F}{J} x_{2} \\
\begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{x_{1}} \\
\dot{x_{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & -\frac{F}{J}
\end{bmatrix}}_{A}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_{1} \\
x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
+
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ \frac{1}{J}
\end{bmatrix}}_{B}
u
$$

Is it correct? I've tried to double check my work using Laplace transform. 
$$
G = \frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{1}{J s^{2} + Fs} 
$$

This is the code

```
>> syms J F
>> b = 1;
>> a = [J, F, 0];
>> [A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(b,a)

A =
[ -F/J, 0]
[    1, 0]

B =
     1
     0
C =
[ 0, 1/J]
D =
0
```

Are the results same? Why `B` in Matlab has no `1/J`?

Comment: There is no real point in keeping $x_1$ around. Just use $\dot{\theta}$ as the state variable.

Comment: I am ignorant in tf/ss terminology,  but I can say that your system for $\dot x_1,\dot x_2$ is correct.  I wonder why $Y(s)=1$ is the correct choice. Maybe $Y(s)=J$ should be used? (I don't see any explicit output variable here to begin with...)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday, why $Y(s) = 1$? who said so? This is ratio.  take the Laplace transform of the differential equation (i.e. $J s^{2} Y(s) + F s Y(s) = U(s) $ and get the ratio of the output to the input (i.e. $Y(s)/U(s)$).

Comment: @copper.hat, actually there is no need for $x_{3}$ not $x_{1}$. the latter represents the angular position which is kind of suitable to name it so that once we get the solution, we can plot it with respect to time.

Comment: Well, you can solve the single dimensional system in $\dot{\theta}$ and then integrate to get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done your calculations correctly and the results are the same. It looks like different because there are infinitely many state space representation of a system, depending on the choice of state variables.

However, your state space representation is incomplete. Because your system does not have an "output" where you can select a linear combination of the states, using a $C$ matrix, i.e. $y=Cx$.

You can put $1/J$ to either $B$ or $C$ matrix. It is the difference between your transfer function and

$$\frac{1/J}{s^2+(F/J)s}$$

Comment: I can get the solution of the system with no need of $C$. So, $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$ is enough to acquire the solution. $x(t) = e^{At}x_{o} + e^{At} \int_{t_{o}}^t e^{A \tau} B u (\tau) d \tau $. This is because $A$ is time-invariant. With the results that I got, the angular velocity approaches zero when the time goes to infinity. It seems my solution is correct.

Comment: You get the solution of "states" not "outputs". In the transfer function you implicitly select the state $x_2$ as output, i.e. $C=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. You could select a different output, like the angle itself. Then your transfer function would be different while state solution is the same.